# Rollovers stop links working in IE8 (WP child theme)

Tags: javascript, css, html, internet-explorer, wordpress-theming

I made a child theme of [Destin Basic](https://wordpress.org/themes/destin-basic/) which works in Firefox/Safari/Chrome for it's primary audience. Colleagues stuck on IE8 also want to use it but links don't work. I didn't realise IE8 issue with `figure` or `figcaption` tags, which rollovers are based on.

Parent theme uses ['Julia'](http://tympanus.net/Development/HoverEffectIdeas/index2.html) rollover - CSS seems to hide `a` as 'View more' doesn't show. In IE8, image changes pointer but link doesn't fire (and text not on dimmed background, etc.).

I'm too far down the line now so just trying to solve links issue. I've been going over and over various options but not sure what's best approach:

1. Try to figure out scripting to get HTML5shiv to work (parent theme link doesn't seem to help)?
       `<!--[if IE]><script src="<?php echo BAVOTASAN_THEME_URL; ?>/library/js/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->`
2. Other scripting solution (in head or selectivizr, Respond, CSS Pie)?
3. Add conditional statements to put `divs` in amongst code then style for IE?
4. Change all to `divs` and style for both IE8 and modern browsers?

Code from functions.php:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php if ( is_front_page() ) { ?>
<div class="item">
<figure class="effect-julia">
<?php
if ( has_post_thumbnail() )
the_post_thumbnail( 'home' );
else
echo '<img src="' . BAVOTASAN_THEME_URL . '/library/images/no-image.jpg" alt="" />';
?>
<figcaption>
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<div>
<p><?php echo wp_trim_words( strip_shortcodes( get_the_excerpt() ) , 10 ); ?></p>
<p class="more-link-p"><?php _e( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'destin' ); ?></p>
</div>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php _e( 'View more', 'destin' ); ?></a>
</figcaption>
</figure>
</div>
```

I'm fine with regular CSS but not sure what's happening with the scripting. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it helps anyone else, here's what I did to improve how my Destin Basic child theme looks on IE8...

CSS: I couldn't add backgrounds on both `<p>`, to make them read over homepage images - removed them instead. Be aware the following code also affects Category listings by taking out the 'Continue reading' links - but each heading is a link anyway. (Not great accessibility practice, I know, but neither are the links themselves.)

```
.more-link-p {
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)"; }
.entry-content .more-link-p {
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)"; }
```

I used the following to reinstate the dark transparent effect on the images (so white text reads):

```
.item image {
background-color: #000000;
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)"; }
```

Also used a variation of the Phark technique to reinstate site logo.

Javascript: couldn't get respond.js to work so nav shows in 'folded' state (mobile-first).

Still couldn't answer main question - how to get homepage post links to work. Instead, I made use of a theme widget - 'sticky container' showing recent posts. Duplicates things for everyone else but at least IE8 users can navigate the site.

EDIT:
I found a JQuery script that makes the links work:

```
<script>
$(document).delegate("figure", "click", function() {
   window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
});
</script>
```